# Node.js Juice inliner

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm trying to use 'juice inlining tool' to make all the internal CSS into inline attribute. However, when I try to import a file, it requires passing a callback as a parameter and I am having difficulty doing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

By the way, I am using Node.js and I have already installed juice package globally and locally.

```
var juice=require('juice');
var inlinecss =juice.juiceFile('./email.html',callback(err,html));
console.log(inlinecss);
callback(err,html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'm using Juice...

```
var fs = require('fs');
var juice = require('juice'); 

var source = fs.readFileSync('./email.html', 'utf-8');
var inlinecss = juice(source, {removeStyleTags: true, preserveMediaQueries: true});

console.log(inlinecss);
```